# In which case/senario should I use GPU( instead of CPU) to run my program?

Tags: optimization, gpu

UPDATE: OK I will try to write some code and find out.

---

If I have a program which runs like this:

1. it picks 20 words from a dictionary each time. ( This dictionary contains 100,000 words)
2. it combine this 20 words into a sentence. (e.g. `good cats are always nice to me`)
3. it run a local function ( e.g. There is a local Class which defined a method, e.g. `MyTool.validate_sentence("good dogs are always nice to me")` )

will this be run faster if using GPU?

programming language is C/Rust.

thanks a lot!

Comment: No. There's too much overhead.

Comment: You can also try and find out.

Comment: point 3, means the program will call a local method using the `sentence` generated in step2. I updated my question

Comment: What does a "local function" mean in this context? Is the function coded for the GPU, or CPU, or both?

Comment: The situation seems constructed. If (_if_) the GPU would be able to pick these words faster than a "regular" program. What would you do with them?

Comment: this local function is just a ordinary function, just like the `hello world`  function,  not special coded for GPU, or CPU

Comment: Why is the question tagged both C and Rust; they both don't have classes (arguably Rust, but these are called structs).

Comment: @TedLyngmo I would choose GPU of course. because this program runs under CPU will cost me 100 years...

Comment: @Siwei If that's the case, show the program

Comment: If the function is a "normal" function, there is no point where the GPU is involved, thus the program won't run faster or slower on a GPU. Certainly not with 20 words, or about 100 characters (depending on the language).

Comment: @9769953  OK I changed the tags. removed `c`, `rust` .

Comment: It sounds like you should really try and find out. Especially if you know it will take 100 years on a CPU, you've all the time in the world to code it for GPU as well.

Comment: "_will this be run faster if using GPU?_" - possibly, but what's the point if you haven't figured out how to deal with the information exchange?

Comment: @TedLyngmo  Thanks a lot, I will try and find out.

Comment: @9769953 thank you for your clue, yes I need a try and find out.

Comment: First you should probably think about what data structures are going to be suitable. Very likely in this context, this is probably a micro-optimization.

Comment: Assuming the words are picked randomly and the sentence is combined from the words randomly, and per program run only one sentence is generated, the slowest part probably will be your local function. From your question I assume this function is a C/Rust function running on the CPU. Then the overhead for generating a random number and loading the words combined into a sentence is negligible and not much parallelizable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, Yes Running this type of data will out-perform CPU.

Long answer, if its is ( stream-able), what I mean is that if you can have your data structured in such a way that its iterable and can be emitted one by one to some consuming end, then yes.

But about the programing language you use, I am only able to tell you that in languages such as C and Rust, definitely, you'll find libraries that support your Gpu Api, like running your code on Cuda threads for Nvidia and so on...